# Boost rename() function doesn't work

Tags: c++, boost, g++, codeblocks

The compiler doesn't complain while building,and my program says it worked, and creates the folder, but the file hasn't moved. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

char c = 'c';

bool move(){

 if ((bool) rename("C:\\fldr1" "rawr.txt", "C:\\fldr2" "rared.txt") == (true)){
    return true;
 }
 else{
    return false;
 }

}
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{

    if (argv[1] = (c))
    {
        if (is_directory("C:\\fldr2")){

            if (move){
            cout << "Done 1!" << endl;
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "Dir doesn't exist!" << endl;

            if ((bool)create_directory("C:\\fldr2") == (true)){

                if (move){
                    cout << "Done 2!" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Windows 7, CodeBlocks 10.05, G++ 4.4.1, and Boost 1.47

Comment: Are you actually casting the "return value" of `void`-returning functions to `bool` and checking them? Does that compile?

Comment: @larsmans It compiles, but the function isn't called properly or something

Comment: you do understand that you won't get a meaningful value that way, do you?

Comment: @larsmans I won't? Would that be because the rename function isn't meant to return a Boolean value?

Comment: It doesn't return a value at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Avoiding c-style casts helps in avoiding many problems like accidentally doing `if(void)`
- implicit concatenation of strings `"C:\\fldr1" "rawr.txt" == "C:\\fldr1rawr.txt"` also may produce undesired results.
- Boost rename can throw exceptions which you aren't handling either.
- Relying on implicit casting of literal string to boost path is a lesser problem.

You could do something like the following instead:

```
bool move()
{
  path src("C:\\fldr1\\rawr.txt");
  path dest("C:\\fldr2\\rared.txt");

  try {
    rename(src, dest);
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    return false;
  }

  return exists(dest);
}
```

Comment: It works, but I had to change it a bit so it would compile, I copied "path dest("C:\\fldr2\\rared.txt");" to right before the line "return exists(dest);" Thank you!

Comment: @RunningDroid : That doesn't make much sense considering that `dest` is needed for the call to `rename`...

Comment: @ildjarn : I changed it because if i try to compile it as-is the compiler gives me "error: 'dest' was not declared in this scope" (which might be a separate problem)

Comment: @RunningDroid : That wouldn't happen with the code AJG85 has shown. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn Then I guess i have to find a way to get the gremlins out of my computer :)

Comment: I should have put a disclaimer I didn't actually compile this I was going from memory of using boost filesystem like 2 years ago. Just giving the general idea in actual production code I would avoid hard coded paths, not have `using namespace` directives, and make wrapper objects and interfaces for boost ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I think you meant

```
if (move()){
```

instead of

```
if (move){
```

The second case tests if the `move` function exists, i.e. its pointer is not NULL (which is always true), the first case tests if the move succeeded.

Comment: The file still isn't moved, Is the problem with the way I call the rename() function?

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (move)
```

Here you are testing that the function pointer is not null - you need to actually call the function. Try

```
if(move())
```